# Getting error "TypeError: got an unexpected keyword argument" but argument is in function definition

Tags: python, typeerror, decorator, keyword-argument, yfinance

I have a function defined as the following:

```
import yfinance
from retry import retry

@retry(tries=3, delay=5)
def get_yfinance(tickers, start=None, end=None, interval='1h'):
    logging.info(f'Downloading data for {len(tickers)}')
    ticker_string = ' '.join(tickers)
    df = yfinance.download(ticker_string, group_by = 'ticker', interval=interval, start=start, end=end, prepost=True)
    df2 = df.stack(level=0).rename_axis(['Date', 'Ticker']).reset_index(level=1)
    df2['Date'] = df2['Date'].dt.tz_convert('UTC')
    df2 = df2.rename(columns={'Adj Close': 'AdjClose'})
    logging.info(f'Returned df with shape {df2.shape}')
    return df2
```

When I try to call it like so:

```
etlts = datetime.now()
start = etlts - timedelta(hours=1)
tickers = sidf['Ticker'].to_list()
ydf = get_yfinance(tickers, start=start, end=etlts, interval='1m')
```

I get the following stack trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\yf.py in 
      47 from findata import *
      48 tickers = sidf['Ticker'].to_list()
----> 49 ydf = get_yfinance(tickers=tickers, start=start, interval='1m')

C:\python39\envs\trad\lib\site-packages\decorator.py in fun(*args, **kw)
    229         def fun(*args, **kw):
    230             if not kwsyntax:
--> 231                 args, kw = fix(args, kw, sig)
    232             return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
    233     fun.__name__ = func.__name__

C:\python39\envs\trad\lib\site-packages\decorator.py in fix(args, kwargs, sig)
    201     Fix args and kwargs to be consistent with the signature
    202     """
--> 203     ba = sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
    204     ba.apply_defaults()  # needed for test_dan_schult
    205     return ba.args, ba.kwargs

C:\Python39\lib\inspect.py in bind(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3060         if the passed arguments can not be bound.
   3061         """
-> 3062         return self._bind(args, kwargs)
   3063 
   3064     def bind_partial(self, /, *args, **kwargs):

C:\Python39\lib\inspect.py in _bind(self, args, kwargs, partial)
   3049                 arguments[kwargs_param.name] = kwargs
   3050             else:
-> 3051                 raise TypeError(
   3052                     'got an unexpected keyword argument {arg!r}'.format(
   3053                         arg=next(iter(kwargs))))

TypeError: got an unexpected keyword argument 'interval'
```

This happens with any combination of arguments. It also happens whether I keep or remove the @retry decorator. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: If `interval` is something you recently added, you may need to `reload` the module containing the function.

Comment: The error is coming from `decorator.py`. I don't see how that would even be used if you remove the decorator.

Comment: Mark that was it thank you!